# RGB to Decimal vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hex, decimal, rgb

I googled for a while trying to find a vb.net function that would change RGB input to Decimal.  I know there is the convert.Int32 route but that takes Hex -> decimal.

Comment: if you want to post a self answered question, there should be an actual question in the acceptable format. otherwise some may DV this.

Comment: You didn't [Google](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28MICROSOFT.VISUALBASIC.INFORMATION.RGB%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true) for very long.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid methods from Microsoft.VisualBasic (e.g. you want to be able to easily convert it to C#), you can do it somewhat more efficiently than your suggested answer:

```
Function RGBtoInteger(r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer
    If r > 255 OrElse g > 255 OrElse b > 255 OrElse r < 0 OrElse g < 0 OrElse b < 0 Then
        Throw New ArgumentException("Parameters must be in the range 0..255.")
    End If
    Return (b << 16) + (g << 8) + r
End Function
```

Comment: @Plutonix Oh dear, that wasn't very efficient at all if it gave the wrong answer. Fixed, and changed the rgb to bgr as the usual way goes, in case someone actually uses the code, although OP appears to want rgb.

Comment: Note to passers-by: `(b << 16) + (g << 8) + r` mimics the return of VB's `Information.RGB`; whereas `(r << 16) + (g << 8) + b`  would be the equivalent of the OP's version.  Take your pick. (+1)

Comment: Thanks Plutonix and Andrew for your site ettiquette tips and much more efficient function.  I have never used the bit shift operator before and will have to read up on what << does exactly.   

I do have one question about / critique of your function.  When I tried r =0,  g= 32, b =1  (Hex is #00201), your function gave a different result than mine.   Mine matched the Convert.ToInt32("00201", 16) output giving 512, but yours returned 8193.  Might this have to do with single digit vs two digit hexadecimal values?  Anyway.  I don't care about the down votes, I'm here to learn and share.

Comment: @CalfordMath (0, 32, 1) would be #002001. The usual way of representing RGB in a number is for the blue to have the highest value, so it would be #012000, i.e. the opposite way to what you are using. If there was also an alpha channel, it would be written ARGB, and the A would occupy the highest byte.

Comment: @CalfordMath `I don't care about the down votes`  but each DVd question gets you one step closer to a ban or question throttle; and a DV'd questions ranks lower in Google and search results, so the answers will help fewer people; and it it more likely to be closed and/or deleted.  Were it deleted it would now probably bother Mr Morton more, as he would lose 20 rep and 2 ticks towards his silver VB badge.  DVs matter.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the function I created, may it prove useful  ( I know I reinvented the wheel with my conversion from base 10 to 16... but it was fun.  I'm a math geek):

```
Public Function RGBtoDecimal(red As Integer, green As Integer, blue As Integer) As Long
    Dim dec As Long = 0
    Dim n, r As Integer
    'write each colour as base 16

    'blue first, starting with smallest power of 16 right to left
    n = blue
    Dim j As Integer = 0
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1
        r = CInt(Math.Round(16 * ((n / 16) - Int(n / 16))))
        n = CInt(Int(n / 16))
        dec = CLng(dec + (r * (16 ^ j)))
        j += 1
    Next

    'green
    n = green
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1
        r = CInt(Math.Round(16 * ((n / 16) - Int(n / 16))))
        n = CInt(Int(n / 16))
        dec = CLng(dec + (r * (16 ^ j)))
        j += 1
    Next

    'red
    n = red
    For i As Integer = 0 To 1
        r = CInt(Math.Round(16 * ((n / 16) - Int(n / 16))))
        n = CInt(Int(n / 16))
        dec = CLng(dec + (r * (16 ^ j)))
        j += 1
    Next
    Return dec
End Function
```

Comment: That doesn't compile with [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx). When you post code here, it is expected that it will ;)

Comment: I added some CInt, CLng to make Strict happy.  It's not quite as succinct as "<<"  :)